# Storing encrypted passwords using Room Database and Keystore System

Tags: android, database, encryption, aes, credentials

I'm developing an offline auth process for users to access their accounts. My idea was to store their hashed & encrypted email and passwords and let them introduce their email and password to auth , i'm using a Room database to store their credentials . The problem is when i try to decrypt their passwords and check if those match the decryption function throws an exception (-1) ,(I'm using the Keystore Sistem , Cipher , tha salt changes constantly with AES-256 algorithm). Any other suggestion to make an offline auth?

```
 fun encryptText(bytes:ByteArray, outputStream: OutputStream ):ByteArray{
        val encryptedBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(bytes)
        outputStream.use {
            it.write(encryptCipher.iv.size)
            it.write(encryptCipher.iv)
            it.write(encryptedBytes.size)
            it.write(encryptedBytes)
        }
        return encryptedBytes
    }
    fun decryptText(inputStream:InputStream):ByteArray{
        Log.d("Test" ,"input decryptor =  " +inputStream.readBytes().decodeToString())
        return inputStream.use {
                val ivSize = inputStream.read()
                val iv = ByteArray(ivSize)
                it.read(iv)

                val encryptedBytesSize = inputStream.read()
                val encryptedBytes = ByteArray(encryptedBytesSize)
                it.read(encryptedBytes)
                 getDecryptCipherForIv(iv).doFinal(encryptedBytes)
        }
    }
@Entity(tableName = "account_credentials")
data class AccountCredentials(@PrimaryKey
                              val uuid:String,
                              val firebaseId:String?,
                              @ColumnInfo(name = "password_bytes",typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB) val hashedPassword:ByteArray,
                              @ColumnInfo(name = "email_bytes",typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB) val email:ByteArray
                         )
 
 private fun encryptCredentials(credentials: AccountCredentials):AccountCredentials{
        val passwordStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val emailStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()

        CryptographicManager().encryptText(credentials.email , emailStream)
        CryptographicManager().encryptText(credentials.hashedPassword , passwordStream)

        return credentials.copy(hashedPassword = passwordStream.toByteArray() , email =emailStream.toByteArray() )
    }
```

I have tried to change the data class field to string instead of ByteArray but the same result .

Comment: "i'm using a Room database to store their credentials" - consider using Room with SQLCipher for Android. [This free book](https://commonsware.com/Room/) has three chapters describing how to use SQLCipher for Android with Room, including some approaches for master password management.